# Reset grid data on user edit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

How we can change grid data to present state data if there is any error come from backend on edit of cell ? Currently, i am able to display that error message which is coming from backend but i want to reset cell value once there is any error from backend api. I am using redux with saga in my application. Thanks.

I am using syncfusion grid component.

Comment: Can you post some of the relevant code? Are you wanting to reset the data via react's setState or within redux?

Comment: Hi, I want to reset grid data on update api error. Data is stored in redux store.